# MPI_Scatter with multiple machines

Tags: c, mpi

I´m new in MPI world and i´m a little bit confuse..

I´m using "MPI_Scatter" to "break" an array in multiple parts. But the case is... It works running the program in multiple machines?

My point is: do I have to use something like MPI_Send and MPI_Rcv? Or Scatter can do this? MPI_Scatter only works in a single machine? Can´t find any good reference about this..

Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Scatter` works no matter where the MPI processes are located. It has the same effect as if the root process has executed a loop of `MPI_Send` operations and all other processes have executed a single `MPI_Recv`. As a matter of fact, `MPI_Scatter` is often implemented internally using `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` unless the network equipment supports some kind of work offloading (but in the end it boils down again to a sequence of send- and receive-like events). The same is true for its counterpart `MPI_Gather`, as well as for any other collective communication call in MPI.

MPI is an abstract specification - it only defines the way communicating entities (ranks) interact with the MPI environment (the API) and the result of this interaction. It doesn't care if ranks are processes on the same node, or if they run on a massively parallel supercomputer, or if they communicate across the globe over the Internet. This is best described in the following excerpt from the MPI specification:

> The attractiveness of the message-passing paradigm at least partially stems from its wide portability. Programs expressed this way may run on distributed-memory multiprocessors, networks of workstations, and combinations of all of these. In addition, shared-memory implementations, including those for multi-core processors and hybrid architectures, are possible. The paradigm will not be made obsolete by architectures combining the shared and distributed-memory views, or by increases in network speeds. It thus should be both possible and useful to implement this standard on a great variety of machines, including those "machines" consisting of collections of other machines, parallel or not, connected by a communication network.